# NotifyListeners() don' work appropriately in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

In my splash screen, I am calling  a method from my model class (getting some data from API and putting them into a list). It works and generates the list. But I can't send this list to my listview widget. Here is the relevant code;

**SplashScreen part which is calling model class method (getFixtures)**

```
 class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  List<Fixture> fixtureList = List<Fixture>();
  FixtureData callFixtureData = FixtureData();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SplashScreen.fixtureData = getFixture();
    Timer(
      Duration(seconds: 5),
      () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => WelcomeScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<List<Fixture>> getFixture() async {
    fixtureList = await callFixtureData.getFixtures();
    return fixtureList;
  }
```

**Model class part; I see the list is not null and correct**

```
class FixtureData extends ChangeNotifier {

  List<Fixture> fixtures = List<Fixture>();
  List<Fixture> bets = List<Fixture>();

  //to show in FAB at HomeScreen
  int get betCount {
    return bets.length;
  }

  Future<List<Fixture>> getFixtures() async {
    fixtures = await FootballApi.getFixtureData();
    print(fixtures[0].homeTeam);
    notifyListeners();
    return fixtures;
  }
```

**ListView part. I'm calling the list with final fixture = fixtureData.fixtures[index]; But nothing happens. What am I missing?**

```
class FixtureList extends StatelessWidget {
  final dateFormat = DateFormat('MMMd');
  final timeFormat = DateFormat('Hm');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<FixtureData>(
      builder: (context, fixtureData, child) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final fixture = fixtureData.fixtures[index];
            return FixtureTile(
              date: dateFormat.format(fixture.dateTime),
              time: timeFormat.format(fixture.dateTime),
              homeTeam: fixture.homeTeam,
              awayTeam: fixture.awayTeam,
              homeOdds: fixture.homeOdds,
              drawOdds: fixture.drawOdds,
              awayOdds: fixture.awayOdds,
              isHomeSelected: fixture.homeSelected,
              isDrawSelected: fixture.drawSelected,
              isAwaySelected: fixture.awaySelected,
              homeCallBack: () => fixtureData.updateSelection(fixture, 'home'),
              drawCallBack: () => fixtureData.updateSelection(fixture, 'draw'),
              awayCallBack: () => fixtureData.updateSelection(fixture, 'away'),
            );
          },
          itemCount: fixtureData.fixtures.length,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're using a hacky method to get around correctly using `Future`s

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `getFixture` is a `Future` and  you're somehow doing this without awaiting `SplashScreen.fixtureData = getFixture();` and then using a `Timer` to push the replacement to try and give time for the `Future` to finish it seems.

Answer (score 1):

you should read Provider [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#-example-tab-) or [sample](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) first , this is so wrong , you've never set value to FixtureData.fixtures but in ListView you want to use this !!

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  List<Fixture> fixtureList = List<Fixture>();
  //FixtureData callFixtureData = FixtureData();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   // SplashScreen.fixtureData = getFixture();
   Provider.of<FixtureData>(context, listen: false).getFixtures();

    Timer(
      Duration(seconds: 5),
      () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => WelcomeScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

 // Future<List<Fixture>> getFixture() async {
 //   fixtureList = await callFixtureData.getFixtures();
 //   return fixtureList;
 // }
```

after that you can use your Consumer ...

also make sure ChangeNotifierProvider is an ancestor to this SplashScreen Widget , like :

```
 MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => FixtureData()),
      ],
      child: SplashScreen(),
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I'll read again documentation. Thanks for the links. I am newbie and provider is the most difficult part to understand so far. I have to practice more.